# Issue with MEF and Prism : A duplicate module with the name {0} has been found by the Loader

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I am trying to create a very basic application using Prism, MEF and WPF. I have a WPF application project which has a Shell.xaml and Bootstrapper. Code for BootStrapper is below:

```
public class SimpleMefApplicationBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        //base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(SimpleMefApplicationBootstrapper).Assembly));             
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(PrismApp.Module.Hello.HelloModule).Assembly));
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(PrismApp.Module.Hello.FinishModule).Assembly));
    }        

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        //base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
    }

    protected override IRegionBehaviorFactory ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors()
    {
        var factory = base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors();           

        return factory;
    }
```

In the solution i have another class library which has a View folder, View model Folder and two modules. The two modules are tied to two views so that they can used as a region. It works perfectly if i try to call only one module from botstrapper but not when i call both the modules. It gives me the error details like :

**A duplicate module with the name FinishModule has been found by the Loader.**

I dont understand if both the modules are having different then what is the problem. I tried changing the assemble also for both the modules but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using only one call:

```
public class SimpleMefApplicationBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        //base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(SimpleMefApplicationBootstrapper).Assembly));   

        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(PrismApp.Module.Hello.HelloModule).Assembly));
      //  this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(PrismApp.Module.Hello.FinishModule).Assembly));
    }
```

Comment: i am too stupid for not thinking that but if two modules with different names are in same assembly then we should call only one? is it? because it is working in either case.

Comment: It is the assembly you are deriving from that is needed, so depends where your modules ultimately reside